# Codemirror: How to disable Enter key from completing hint?

Tags: codemirror

As the title states I currently have autcomplete functionality where both the tab and enter keys finish words. I only want to have tab finish hints. How to disable the enter key from completing hints?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to disable this without going into the source code. If someone knows a better answer, then please offer it. However, this is how I disabled it:

1. Navigate to the addon folder in CodeMirror
2. Open the hint addon
3. Open the show-hint.js file
4. Find the line `Enter: handle.pick,` and comment it out by putting `//` in front of the line

Answer (score 1):

According to the [codemirror manual for hint](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_show-hint)

set `hintOptions.extraKeys.Enter = 'newlineAndIndent'` can override the pick behavior of hint when Enter keydown.